# Cython: ctypedef function?

Tags: c++, c, function, typedef, cython

Is it possible to `ctypedef` a function, as it is a common pattern in C++? Like

```
typedef int (*foo)(int, double, char*)

# Cython equivalent
ctypedef int (*foo)(int, double, char*)
```

Or at least to extern it without declaring it directly ? Something similiar to

```
# myheader.h
typedef int (*foo)(int, double, char*)

# mytest.pyx
extern int (*foo)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes that's perfectly possible:

```
ctypedef void (*function_type_name)(int, int)
```

Comment: Oh man, I could have sworn it didn't work.. Maybe I should've tried it with an easier function-typedef before I go on typedeffing them with more arguments. ^^ Sorry, and thank you.

Comment: @Niklas R: if my answer answered your question please consider marking it as such by ticking the green checkmark left of my answer.

Comment: I know how to do. Wanted to checkmark it, but not enough time passed back then. I'm not counting seconds to mark your answer.

Comment: @Niklas R: oh sorry, excuse me, I usually say it automatically with people that seem new :)